# sparkles are beneath the donat not above it

Tags: particles

[image]
following blender guru in his tutorial for beginners i couldn't make sparkles at the right way .. the hair is supposed to be above and under the icing but it's only above .. when i rendered as object and selected the sparkle it went beneath the icing and they are not able to seen from above but only in x-ray mode[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got the solution from a guy in the comments here's the solution if any one faced same problem you need to click the arrow behind "source" and turn on "use modifier stack .. [image]

Comment: Or you can just move the particle system above the solidify modifier in modifiers tab